# Liberal thread usage

Tags: c#, multithreading

I'm writing an application which makes several modifications to my GUI, although never will two points access the same part of the GUI thread. The application is entirely thread safe as it stands, and it is easy to understand and see why (I have one invoker which modifies the GUI, the rest modify external class objects which are in turn grabbed - avoiding locks - by the GUI control thread.)

What I'm wondering is this, how far should I go? I mean, each time I've added a thread it's been because my GUI is becoming unresponsive, but I'm a software tester, so that's probably something to do with my inability to wait for half a second for a GUI to refresh.

So, how many threads is a reasonable amount for a small application? Should I be limiting myself to a certain amount? Or should I just go mad and make my GUI smooth and as I like... I guess the real question here, the one which has an answer, is something like:

Is it productive to use multiple threads wherever possible, or is it detrimental to use too many threads, or is it something which should be carefully balanced to produce an efficient but effective application?

Thanks

Comment: What are these threads doing?

Comment: I'll put it straight out there, I'm writing a bot for a game. The bot needs several control elements. It must be able to monitor the game entirely in a visible way (I'm using a large quantity of list views so I can debug in realtime), as well as control it in return. I decided to use a different thread for the a "healer" tool, and at that point I decided I'd also seperate out a few others... They are generally just calling ReadProcessMemory from win32, as well as using SendMessage and making calculations to work out what to do and where to go next...

Comment: +1 for being a perfectly valid and reasonable question

Answer (score 1):

It's important to clearly understand the difference between asynchronous programming and threading. Windows forms applications run in a single threaded apartment but they can still perform asynchronous operations by dispatching tasks on the Windows message queue. Therefore, operations can be performed asynchronously without necessarily requiring a thread. Threading is not always (perhaps not often) the best way of handling asynchronicity.

How many threads should you have? Tricky. Spinning up threads is a relatively expensive operation and it takes a fair bit of memory too, around 1 Mb per thread to store the thread's stack and other housekeeping stuff. There's an argument that says there's no point in having more threads than the number of CPUs available to run them, and the best situation is one thread per CPU core. More than that just leads to unnecessary context switching and memory use. It is easy to find examples of programs that use many threads to take up 0% of the CPU - for example on my system right now, Windows Explorer is using 69 threads to do absolutely nothing. It is difficult to imagine why Explorer needs 69 threads when I've only got a dual-core CPU.  Since you don't know how many cores your program will have available when it runs, or what the other programs on the system will be doing, then you can't really make any assumptions. The answer is always "it depends".

The .NET Framework provides something called the Thread Pool, which releases you from worrying about how many threads to create because the thread pool takes care of all that. It is better to think in terms of tasks, which you submit to the thread pool via a task queue. The thread pool takes tasks from the queue and executes them as and when resources are available. This lets you maintain a responsive UI without having to worry about managing threads. In theory. .NET will optimise the thread pool for the system it is running on.

Jeff Richter has some good information about this in his book ***CLR via C#***.

Comment: To whoever downvoted this: care to share why? I thought the answer was well founded and rather well-written. Or perhaps it's just a Jeffrey Richter fanboy in me talking. Either way, +1.

Comment: I didn't down vote it. I agree with your sentiment, I think it is a perfectly reasonable and valid question, but your comment may be more appropriate on the question itself instead of on my answer.

Comment: My comment was actually directed at whoever downvoted your answer, not the question itself.

Comment: Oh, I beg your pardon. At the moment I read it there were no down votes on my answer so I assumed you meant the question as a whole. Thanks for chasing off my detractor :)

Answer (score 0):

You should look at the [MVC model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller). I know that the usual frameworks for windows in C# don't enforce this very much but if you can separate the data from the showcase, modifying it will become much easier.

Also for the thread number... I tend to avoid them as much as possible but it is not always possible. It leads to all kinds of synchronization issues and race conditions and deadlocks which are somethings pretty hard to figure out and debug properly.

Comment: I disagree. Microsoft's async policy on WinRT for instance (can't find the article right now) is that any operation that takes more than 10 ms should be async.

Comment: Hi @Eric, thanks for your reply. Do you feel the MVC model is applicable to C# for .NET? Much of the codebase of the language appears to encourage thread usage, hence my lack of concern in the first place. I was more _hoping_ to get a confirmation that using threads in such a way is more productive than not. My opinion followed closely what HighCore said - I always thought the rule was 25ms though.

Comment: spawning threads using a thread pool is not a bad idea. I agree with using MVC for such a case. Since the OP is making a BOT then it makes sense that he would have a thread for almost any action taken. The thread is not going to be active all the time so if he just makes a que to spawn the threads then he should be ok.

Comment: MVC is language agnostic. As a general rule of thumb, you should keep components as independent as possible. This is useful because threading in UIs is tricky as you often need to run the updates on the UI thread, leading to all kinds of complications. If your model is independent of your UI, you will avoid cross-thread operation errors

Comment: also to answer HighCore, yeah, I agree that "long" operations should be threaded, depending on what long is for you. But you don't need many threads for that, a thread that processes a message queue is often more than enough to split the UI and the model correctly.